# Place border around content in CSS Grid item when using place-content: center

Tags: css, border, css-grid

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: hsl(211, 47%, 20%);
  background: hsl(211, 47%, 30%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [main-start] minmax(0, 1fr) [main-end nav-start] auto [nav-end];
}

main {
  background: hsl(211, 47%, 30%);
  border: .5em solid white;
  border-radius: .5em;
  grid-row: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto, 200px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, 200px);
  place-content: center;
 }

.gr1 { grid-row: 1 }
.gr2 { grid-row: 2 }
.gr3 { grid-row: 3 }
.gc1 { grid-column: 1 }
.gc2 { grid-column: 2 }
.gc3 { grid-column: 3 }
.gc4 { grid-column: 4 }

nav {
  background: hsl(211, 47%, 30%);
  grid-row: nav;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: hsl(211, 47%, 20%);
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <button id="" class="gr1 gc1">Buttton 1</button>
        <button id="" class="gr1 gc2">Buttton 2</button>
        <button id="" class="gr1 gc3">Buttton 3</button>
        <button id="" class="gr1 gc4">Buttton 4</button>
        <button id="" class="gr2 gc1">Buttton 5</button>
        <button id="" class="gr2 gc2">Buttton 6</button>
        <button id="" class="gr2 gc3">Buttton 7</button>
        <button id="" class="gr2 gc4">Buttton 8</button>
        <button id="" class="gr3 gc1">Buttton 9</button>
        <button id="" class="gr3 gc2">Buttton 10</button>
        <button id="" class="gr3 gc3">Buttton 11</button>
        <button id="" class="gr3 gc4">Buttton 12</button>
    </main>
    <nav>
        <button id="deleteDB">Delete Database</button>
        <button id="initDB">Initialize Database</button>
        <button id="">Menu 3</button>
    </nav>
</body>
```

My Question is:

How do i move the border from around the "main" area to the content of the main area? I want to make the grid gap white also.

Right now the Buttons respond correctly when I resize (responsive).

The reason i use grid-auto-rows and grid-auto-columns is because the amount of buttons is dynamic (comes from a database). I have not shown any JavaScript.

I could probably use JavaScript to do the layout but I think CSS is better.

Thank-you for any input.

Comment: consider nesting the button inside div where the div will be the grid item and then you add the border to button

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you want to make a border around the button content and not the grid? One way would be to wrap the button inside a div and then add the border to the button, as Temani said. Another way, if you are a bit lazy, is to make the button have a fixed width, and then set the margin position to auto to center it.

Then you just add this:

```
    button {
    width: 80px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```